# How can i get the value which role is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i get the which a element is clicked i cant take can you help me ? I am working with react 0.14

CODE :

```
const role = ['admin', 'user', 'x', 'y']

menuClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}

<ul>
  {role.map((item)=> <li > <a  onClick={this.menuClick} > {item}</a> </li> )}  
</ul>
```

Comment: <ul>
          {role.map((item)=> <li > <a  onClick={this.menuClick} > {item}</a> </li> )}  

  </ul>

Comment: You can edit your question. Don't post a comment!